# How to properly add OAuth2 Popup in existing PyQt5 Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, pyqt5

I'm pretty new to PyQt, and I've managed to fumble my way through putting together a working Application using Qt Designer. However, I need to add an OAuth2 flow to sign into a particular service, and I'm having trouble getting that to fit in my existing Application.

I found a great example that takes care of the PyQt5/OAuth2 login in Github (https://github.com/alonraiz/QT-OAuth-Example) - as long as I run it standalone. I'm now trying to integrate it so that it pops up when the user selects a specific menu item... and I'm having trouble.

The default code uses this:

```py
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = LoginWindow(app)
```

Since I already have an app, I've tried just calling:

```py
    browser = LoginWindow(app)
```

Using my existing app object. Which then gets me to this error:
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running

Which seems to make sense. So I delete this:

```py
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But then I just get nothing.

Based on my limited PyQt5 experience, I'm sure I'm going about this completely wrong...

Here is an example illustrating where I'm at right now. Appreciate any help!

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

import sys
from urllib.parse import urlencode, parse_qs
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


"""
login   anxious-elephant@example.com
password    Frantic-Magpie-Tame-Cow-9
"""

ClientId = '0oamu4rr08hdGKd9u0h7'
RedirectUrl = 'www.oauth.com/playground/authorization-code.html'
RedirectScheme = 'https://'
Scopes = ['photo offline_access']

ResponseType = 'code'

Headers = {'client_id': ClientId, 'redirect_uri': RedirectScheme+RedirectUrl, 'response_type': ResponseType,
           'scope': str.join(' ', Scopes), 'state': 'RT6TfGb4jEWbz7SI'}

AuthUrl = 'https://dev-396343.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?{headers}'.format(
    headers=urlencode(Headers))


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(234, 167)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 234, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionLogin = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionLogin.setObjectName("actionLogin")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionLogin)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionLogin.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login"))


class RequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super(RequestInterceptor, self).__init__()
        self.app = app

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        if RedirectUrl == (info.requestUrl().host()+info.requestUrl().path()):
            params = parse_qs(info.requestUrl().query())
            if 'code' in params.keys():
                print('OAuth code is {code}'.format(code=params['code']))
                self.app.quit()
                # return params['code']


class LoginWindow(QWebEngineView):
    logged_in = QtCore.pyqtSignal(['QString'])

    def __init__(self, app):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__()
        self.nam = self.page()
        self.app = app
        self.setUrl(QUrl(AuthUrl))
        self.show()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        interceptor = RequestInterceptor(app)
        self.page().profile().setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
        # This needs enabled to get the working example running:
        # sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.page().toHtml(self.callable)

    def callable(self, data):
        self.html = data


class MainMenu(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, dialog, mainapp):
        global fn
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)
        self.actionLogin.triggered.connect(self.login)
        self.mainapp = mainapp

    def login(self):
        print("login")
        browser = LoginWindow(self.mainapp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This doesn't work
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    menu = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    prog = MainMenu(menu, app)
    menu.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    # This works:
    # app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # browser = LoginWindow(app)
```

What I'm looking to do is get the OAuth flow work as a popup from the main application rather than a standalone application (or get both applications living together in peace and harmony).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read the PyQt5<sup>(1)</sup> docs so you know how to use the class generated by Qt Designer. Considering the above, the solution is to inherit from QMainWindow and use the Qt Designer class as the interface class. The interceptor object is a local variable that also generates a problem, so that it does not happen, pass the window as parent.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode, parse_qs

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineCore, QtWebEngineWidgets


"""
login   anxious-elephant@example.com
password    Frantic-Magpie-Tame-Cow-9
"""

ClientId = "0oamu4rr08hdGKd9u0h7"
RedirectUrl = "www.oauth.com/playground/authorization-code.html"
RedirectScheme = "https://"
Scopes = ["photo offline_access"]

ResponseType = "code"

Headers = {
    "client_id": ClientId,
    "redirect_uri": RedirectScheme + RedirectUrl,
    "response_type": ResponseType,
    "scope": str.join(" ", Scopes),
    "state": "RT6TfGb4jEWbz7SI",
}

AuthUrl = "https://dev-396343.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?{headers}".format(
    headers=urlencode(Headers)
)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(234, 167)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 234, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionLogin = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionLogin.setObjectName("actionLogin")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionLogin)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionLogin.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login"))


class RequestInterceptor(QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    codeChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        if RedirectUrl == (info.requestUrl().host() + info.requestUrl().path()):
            params = parse_qs(info.requestUrl().query())
            if "code" in params.keys():
                code = params["code"][0][0]
                print("OAuth code is {code}".format(code=params["code"][0][0]))
                self.codeChanged.emit(code)


class LoginWindow(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    codeChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(AuthUrl))
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        interceptor = RequestInterceptor(self)
        self.page().profile().setUrlRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
        self.show()

        self.interceptor.codeChanged.connect(self.codeChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.page().toHtml(self.callable)

    def callable(self, data):
        self.html = data


class MainMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionLogin.triggered.connect(self.login)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.code_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(self.code_label)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def login(self):
        self.browser = LoginWindow()
        self.browser.codeChanged.connect(self.onCodeChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onCodeChanged(self, code):
        self.code_label.setText(code)
        # self.browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    menu = MainMenu()
    menu.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

<sup>(1) [Using the Generated Code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code)</sup>